# VBA: New collection -> A module is not a valid type

Tags: vba, excel, module, ide

I'm trying to use a collection as part of a function, however I keep getting the error: "A module is not a valid type" on compile.

Even if the function simply defines a collection, I get the same:

```
Function CountUniqueTags()
    Dim table As Collection
    Set table = New Collection
End Function
```

This code is in a standard module, but the error implies I should be writing this in a class module, but Collection is a built-in class so I don't see the issue?

Comment: I am not getting any error... Can you post the complete code?

Comment: I suspect you have a module named Collection. (Bad idea!)

Answer (score 8):

This was making me go crazy for a while, too.  I had code in one file that worked fine.  Copied the code, went to a different file, added and renamed the module, pasted in the code, and suddenly the code will not compile!  I read several unhelpful answers before I saw one that gave me the clue I needed.

The error message states "A **module** is not a valid type" (note the emphasis on the word "module").  That means the Type you are specifying (in your case, "Collection") is also the name of a Module.

If you rename the Module "Collection" to some other name, the error will go away.

Comment: I wish we could (as a community) accept a helpful answer some time after no answer has been accepted by the OP. +1 from me for saving me a headache. (Turns out the compiler error in German translations is - when translated back to English: `A module doesn't have a valid type`, which isn't only wrong, but also utter nonsense and not helpful at all.)

Comment: Even worse, in Japanese, it just says "Invalid module".