# Worksheet_FollowHyperlink VBA cannot be created

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a VBA newbie and I am trying to replicate the following code to help me show a hidden sheet when clicking on a hyperlink.

Code taken from https://www.computergaga.com/blog/how-to-hyperlink-to-a-hidden-worksheet-in-excel/

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

Dim ShtName As String

ShtName = Left(Target.SubAddress, InStr(1, Target.SubAddress, "!") - 1)

Sheets(ShtName).Visible = xlSheetVisible

Sheets(ShtName).Select


End Sub
```

I followed the steps, choosing the table of content sheet with prepopulated hyperlinks, viewing code of this sheet and choose Worksheet and FollowHyperlink.
However, *I cannot click on FollowHyperlink*. It kept generating an error message: **A module is not a valid type**. This prevents me from creating a private sub and utilizing the code above.

Please help me with the error.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have any other modules in the workbook and what are they named?

Comment: Hi BigBen, thank you very much for your quick response. I did have a module called hyperlink. I think this is the cause as when I rename this module, I can create the sub code above, yayyyy! Thank you very much again!

Comment: Yes, that is definitely the cause. This is pretty much a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761040/vba-new-collection-a-module-is-not-a-valid-type), except yours is a different type (`Hyperlink` vs `Collection`).

Comment: Right, I did see this mentioned in some posts, but I could not relate to my situation at that time. Thanks BigBen again!